# Optimizing nested RSpec contexts and examples

Tags: ruby, rspec

I really like the self-documenting nature of RSpec tests so I often create many nested contexts and examples in order to clarify the intent of the tested objects and the situation in which they are being tested, like in this simplified example:

```rb
RSpec.describe Foo do
  ... some let definitions ...

  context 'when used properly' do
    before do
      something_expensive_to_calculate
    end 

    it 'is successful' do
      ...
    end
    
    it 'has benefits' do
      ....
    end
    
    it 'has the power to change the world' do
      ...
    end
  end

  context 'in evil hands' do
    ... more nested contexts and examples ...
  end
end
```

Such approach, however, seems to repeat the setup phase for each of the examples and because of that slows the tests down considerably.

The question is whether there are some patterns which allow to add a documentation text to a group of assertions (like I use 'it'), but which would not set up the context as 'it' does.

I found before(:all) blocks. Unfortunately `let` variables cannot be used in them and so it is not a solution for me. Another solution would be let variables with context lifetimes, but it seems there is no such thing in RSpec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestProf has something that you seem to need https://test-prof.evilmartians.io/#/recipes/let_it_be

```rb
let_it_be(:foo) { very_expensive_setup }
```

Which would instantiate the `:foo` once and keep its state for all the examples.

Make sure you also ready through [caveates](https://test-prof.evilmartians.io/#/recipes/let_it_be?id=caveats) as this is not just simply better `let`

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure if I properly understand your question but perhaps what you are looking for is the subject syntax ?

```rb
RSpec.describe Foo do
  ... some let definitions ...
  context 'when used properly' do
     subject { do_some stuff } 
        
     it 'whatever' do 
       expect(something).to_not eq true
       expect(subject).to eq false 
     end
  end
end
```

The subject clause allows you to take a series of actions relating to something you are trying to test and re-use the actions inside the subject clause over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for you input. But I think that if several examples come after single subject, then the subject will be created for each example anew. So it is not very different from before blocks.

Comment: @kyku each example `it/specify` yes, but not each expectation. Subject's and let's are memorized so the blocks will be called once per example. Also I suggest using `aggregate_failures: true` in this case.

Comment: @Grzegorz, my intent was to have the subject / let objects cached between all the examples in an example group (i.e. context / describe).

Comment: Check out https://test-prof.evilmartians.io/#/recipes/let_it_be but it's a tradeoff, I'd not recommend it as a go-to solution for all your spec - RSpec assumes "clean" state. It works great though when the setup is costly.

Comment: @Grzegorz, it looks promising. Please add this as a separate answer, so that I can mark it as a solution.